# What exactly Gnome does when launching a desktop app?

Tags: gnome, xorg, wayland

I'm using Zorin OS, but I believe the same thing applies to all Ubuntu based distros.

When launching an app via search on overview screen, Gnome has the following behavior:

- If application is not running already, launches it
- If application is running already, brings its current windows to foreground

How exactly is it doing the "bring window to foreground" part?

For example, inspecting Google Chrome's `.desktop` file from `/usr/share/applications` (installed via `.deb`), I see that the `Exec` command is `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U`, which always creates a new window. So, Gnome is clearly doing something else when application is already running.

I am trying to achieve a global shortcut for each of mine most used apps and I want that exact same behavior, "open or bring it to foreground if already running".

I kinda did it already writing a script using `wmctrl`, however that solution doesn't seem very reliable nor elegant since I am using grep to find current application's windows. Also, it doesn't work with wayland if I'm not mistaken.

If I could trigger Gnome somehow, it would be a much better solution.

Answer (score 1):

GNOME Shell's window manager code always tries to associate each window with its .desktop file (based on WM_NAME and other heuristics). For example, that's how it knows what app icon and title to show in the top-bar, independently from the actual window's title. Internally this is the "shell-window-tracker" module.

So when the launcher wants to start an app, it first asks the window manager to bring forth a window that's associated with the same .desktop file, and only executes the program if there aren't any matching windows.

But note that **the same** GNOME Shell is both the app launcher and also the window manager. It doesn't make any external API calls to achieve this – the overview/launcher code just uses internal functions to communicate with the window management code, as they're both running in the same process.

To achieve the same externally, you'll need to use Shell's D-Bus APIs, although it doesn't seem to have any for launching a specific app, so you may need to use `org.gnome.Shell.Eval()` and call Shell-internal GJS functions that way.

Untested:

```
busctl --user call org.gnome.Shell \
    /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell Eval \
    s "Shell.AppSystem.get_default().lookup_app('foo.desktop').activate();"
```

Comment: Thanks for your very clarifying answer. I tried that, but I got this error `bs false "ReferenceError: Shell is not defined"`